# Media fetch issue using gatsby-source-wordpress plugin RequestError: Timeout awaiting 'request' for 30000ms

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am using gatsby-source-wordpress to fetch data and during gatsby build or gatsby develop I have media fetch issue RequestError: Timeout awaiting 'request' for 30000ms. I have also increased the timeout time in the schema option and have also used "GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=5 gatsby develop" but nothing is working. How can I solve this issue? I am quite lost in this issue

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/plugin-options.md#typemediaitemlocalfilerequestconcurrency), use it like:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
  options: {
    type: {
      MediaItem: {
        localFile: {
          requestConcurrency: 50,
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

It defaults to `100`, try lowering this if the WordPress server crashes on import.

Comment: I am using like this 
 type: {
          MediaItem: {
            localFile: {
              requestConcurrency: 5,
            },
            
          }

Comment: Have you tried changing your command to `"build": "GATSBY_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=600000 NODE_ENV=production gatsby build"` (or develop)

Comment: My total Media items are 2100 and I think maybe it's because of large number of media items

Comment: You should be able to manage them (with time) configuring the proper options